# Text to csv in python

Tags: python

*Edit*

I have text output that goes in the form:

SANFRAN
Temp 1 72
Hum 2 70
Time 3 12:00
SANFRAN
Temp 1 74
Hum 2 68
Time 3 12:01
SANFRAN
Temp 1 76
Hum 2 65
Time 3 12:02

... fyi the output is either City (e.g. SANFRAN) or "  "

and I would like to write this to a csv, like this:

SANFRAN, 72, 70, 12:00
SANFRAN, 74, 68, 12:01
SANFRAN, 76, 65, 12:02

(this is a simplified version of the original question)

How can I read in each row and then by FID ... then writerow on each occurrence of SANFRAN... where writerow will place each FID in order as per the desired output above

When I read in the row it is a string but I can not seem to be able split it up with splits(" ") [I then tried reading the file into a csv so I got a list instead per row but that can not be the way to do this pythonically]... then I could do a if/switch style statement to pick out what FID this row is 
=> but that all seems like a dogs dinner again!

I was hoping I would specify a pattern as the text in (all new line) does follow a pattern (although in the real text I am trying to parse sometimes FIDs are not present in each record- in which case I was going to either repeat the last seen value, or leave a blank.. or a combo of both!)

Comment: What google tells you?

Comment: There are many possible solutions to this, can you provide what you have tried? Even if what you have doesn't work at all, it will help us understand the specific code/concepts with which you are struggling. A real data sample would help too.

Comment: some code and expected output would be a big help

Comment: edited... sorry about the crappy first post!

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most pretty solution, but I just tested it:

```
import csv

string = """SANFRAN
Temp 1 72
Hum 2 70
Time 3 12:00
SANFRAN
Temp 1 74
Hum 2 68
Time 3 12:01
SANFRAN
Temp 1 76
Hum 2 65
Time 3 12:02"""

strList = string.split('\n')

#creates result.csv file to write results to
f = csv.writer(open("result.csv", "wb+"))
#writes header row
f.writerow(["City", "Temp", "Hum", "Time"])

count = 1
tempList = []
for x in strList:
    temp = x.split(' ')

    if(count == 1):
        tempList.append(temp[0])
    else:
        tempList.append(temp[2])

    #Completed csv row
    if(count%4==0):
        f.writerow([tempList[0],tempList[1],tempList[2], tempList[3]])
        tempList = []
        count = 0
    count = count + 1
```

Comment: Thanks man... I am hoping for something a bit smarter though, that can recognise the pattern of (Field+FID+Value). Perhaps that isn't possible though??

Comment: Aha, something more dynamic? Could you edit your question with a bit more detail? Are you saying that there might be multiple values for each row? That it isn't always just three (Field-fieldID-value)?

Comment: Hey Zar... I want to pull a configurable set of fields in the long run... one set of fields get written to one csv file, another defined set of fields to another csv file and any remaining fields get dumped to a third file [not sure what format that will be yet/ would be best... I just want to check per record those 3rd set of fields match on field+fid+value]

Comment: Will you know the fields before the run? Can they be hard coded into a list that is then checked or must this too be dynamic?

Comment: I will know the first two sets of fields before I run... the 3rd file is just a catch all for the other fields so I won't know them